# Possible Python Flask Memory Leak

Tags: python, flask, memory

Hoping someone can help me address this issue.
I've got a very simple Flask server running in a docker container which accepts a new frame every time the `/api/feed_image` endpoint is called. The image passed through that endpoint then streams to the index.html from `/video_feed`.

The application works as expected initially, however, when I watch the resources being consumed using `docker stats` the memory usage slowly climbs until the entire system crashes.
Does anyone know what I could have missed or have any suggestions?

Thanks!

```py
import os
import sys

from azure.iot.device.aio import IoTHubModuleClient
from flask import Response
from flask import request
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
import datetime
import time
import numpy as np
import cv2
import queue

frameQueue = queue.Queue()
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/video_feed")
def video_feed():
    print(len(frameQueue))
    return Response(generate(), mimetype="multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame")

@app.route("/api/feed_image", methods=['POST'])
def read_image():

    r = request
    nparr = np.fromstring(r.data, np.uint8)

    frameQueue.put(cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR))

def generate():
    global frameQueue
    while True:
        outputFrame = frameQueue.get()
        if outputFrame is None:
            continue
        
        (flag, encodedImage) = cv2.imencode(".jpg", outputFrame)

        if not flag:
            continue
        yield(b'--frame\r\n' b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + bytearray(encodedImage) + b'\r\n')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='5001', debug=True, threaded=True, use_reloader=False)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a long time I solved my own problem.
Turns out because I wasn't returning a Response object at the end of `read_image()`, Flask was generating an exception, which must have been caching in the background:

```sh
172.18.0.4 - - [22/Apr/2021 00:09:25] "POST /api/feed_image HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1953, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1968, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2098, in make_response
    "The view function did not return a valid response. The"
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
```

Adding a return statement solved the problem.

```py
@app.route("/api/feed_image", methods=['POST'])
def read_image():
    
    ...

    return Response(status=201)
```

Perhaps someone would have an explanation as to why this would happen?
Either way, I hope this helps someone!